# Should I contact the recruiter or should I wait?

Tags: interviewing, follow-up

About 6 weeks ago I applied for a job and I was invited for a virtual interview within 3 weeks.
I then was contacted for a phone interview by the recruiter after a week, and after the phone interview the recruiter told me he would transfer my resume to the hiring manager.

It has been a week now and I still haven't heard anything from him. When I log into my account and check my job status it says "initial screening" but when I check on their website without logging in, it says the job is no longer available.

Does this mean I didn't get the job or am I still under consideration?

Should I contact the recruiter or should I just wait?
I did send him a thank you letter on the day after the phone interview but got no response.

Comment: The removal of the posting from the website may simply mean they aren't accepting any new applicants for the position. Most likely, it got taken down when the interviewing started 3 weeks ago.

Comment: @belete I edited your question to remove the wall of text (http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text). Next time please make your question easy to read yourself.

Answer (score 0):

During interviews, always ask when they expect to get back in touch with you.  Wait a couple days after that date, then you can ask for an update.  When given no date, the general rule of thumb I've seen is to get back in contact no sooner than a week later.  If the recruiter is external to the company you're applying to, you don't have to worry very much about contacting them too soon, as an external recruiter can't really affect the decision.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with a recruiter, internal or external, don't be shy about calling them up, particularly if 1) they didn't give a clear timeline of next steps or events and 2) they haven't contacted you in a week.  Anything could have happened on their end; out-of-office for illness, planned vacation that you didn't know about, etc.

When you call, use a relaxed approach like "Hello [whomever].  I'm just following up on our conversation last week and checking in to make sure that you/the company have everything you need from me to keep things in motion."  If you're leaving a voicemail, trail with "Look forward to hearing from you.  A good number to reach me is xxx-xxx-xxxx".  It's short, pleasant, to the point and leaves the impression that you expect to hear from them.